# LibGDX Stage and Actor, Events and Actor properties

Tags: libgdx, screen, actor, stage

I'm just starting android game development with LibGdx framework.
I read many online tutorial so far and the more I read the more I got confused: ApplicationListener, ApplicationAdapter, Stages, Game, Screens, Actors, Sprites, Images... not mentioning Input and Gesture listeners of all king).

I finally understood what kind of "model" I should use for the game I have in mind (a kind of puzzle game): Game, Screens, Stage and Actor.

So here is my first code.

This is the main application (Game):

```
package com.my.game1;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class MyGame extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create () {
        setScreen(new StarterScreen());
    } 
}
```

This is the main screen class:

```
package com.my.game1;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;

public class StarterScreen implements Screen {

    private Stage stage;
    private float screenW, screenH;
    private Tess tessera;

    @Override
    public void show() {
        tessera = new Tess("image.png");
        stage = new Stage();
        screenW = stage.getViewport().getWorldWidth();
        screenH = stage.getViewport().getWorldHeight();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
        stage.addActor(tessera);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
    }  

}
```

And the following is the class that extends Actor:

```
package com.my.game1;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ActorGestureListener;

public class Tess extends Actor {

    private Texture texture;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public Tess (String img) {
        this.texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(img));
        this.setBounds(0f, 0f, this.texture.getWidth(), this.texture.getHeight());
        this.setOrigin(this.texture.getWidth() / 2, this.texture.getHeight() / 2);
        this.setScale(0.25f);
        this.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
            public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((Tess)event.getTarget()).toggleSelect();
                ((Tess)event.getTarget()).setColor(0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        batch.draw(texture, 0, 0);
    }

    public void finalize() {
        this.texture.dispose();
    }

    public void toggleSelect(){
        this.selected = !this.selected;
        if (this.selected == true)
            this.setColor(0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f);
        else
            this.setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);          
    }
}
```

The screen shows correctly the actor, but I cannot set the Actor's position or its scale, nor the "tap" event seems to get detected; and the color doesn't change.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things were wrong.  First, just on the side, you don't want to call `dispose()` from the Screen's `hide()` method.  `hide()` can be called simply when the screen is turned off, or when the app is switched to the background, and disposing of the `Screen` during that would cause serious issues on resume.

With that out of the way, here's what your Actor should have looked like:

```
package com.my.game1;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Batch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Actor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Touchable;

public class Tess extends Actor {

    private Sprite sprite;
    private boolean selected = false;

    public Tess (String img) {
        this.sprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(img)));
        this.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
        this.setBounds(this.sprite.getX(), this.sprite.getY(), this.sprite.getWidth(), this.sprite.getHeight());
        this.setOrigin(this.sprite.getWidth() / 2, this.sprite.getHeight() / 2);
        this.setScale(0.25f);
        this.addListener(new ActorGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void tap (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                ((Tess)event.getTarget()).toggleSelect();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        sprite.draw(batch);
    }

    @Override
    public void positionChanged(){
        sprite.setPosition(getX(), getY());
    }

    public void toggleSelect(){
        this.selected = !this.selected;
        if (this.selected == true)
            sprite.setColor(0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 1f);
        else
            sprite.setColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);          
    }
}
```

First thing changed: you should use a `Sprite`, not a `Texture`, to handle color, drawing and transformations easily.  `Texture` is possible, but is not as straightforward as `Sprite` is.

Next, you need to call `setTouchable(Touchable.enabled)` inside the actor to actually enable hit detection.  Without this, no touch events are passed to the `Actor`.

After that, with `setBounds()`, you need to use `sprite.getX()` and `sprite.getY()`, to utilize the `Sprite`'s positional values.  Setting them to any arbitrary number seems to disable any touch capacity for that `Actor`.

Another thing, if all of that had been OK, is that you were setting the color twice for each touch, once based on the `selected` field, and then immediately after straight to the dark purple, so I removed the second set and just used your toggle method.

Next, since we have a `Sprite` now, we can use the `draw()` method attached to the `Sprite` itself and feed it the `Batch`, instead of calling the `Batch`'s draw.

Finally, when you want to change the position of the image, call `setPosition` on the actor itself, and utilize an override of the `positionChanged()` method to set the `Sprite`'s position based on the `Actor`'s new position.

Comment: Thanks. You gave me some good advices.

I removed the dispose() call from inside the hide() method; at the beginning that was a splash screen so I meant to dispose it just after to hide it... because non more useful.

About the ActorGestureListener, I assure you it has a tap() method.
Don't know much yet about Events and Event Listener, so I copied the code from a tutorial.

Maybe it was just because I used Texture instead of Sprite, and I was setting bounds to 0,0 and the size of the texture.

I still have to refine some aspects, but now it works and I think I'm on the right way.

Thank you.

Comment: Ah, now I see `tap()`.  I must have looked at it wrong.  I updated my answer to reflect this (and the fact that ActorGestureListener also has touchUp and touchDown methods).  If this worked out for you, could I get an answer accept?

Comment: I don't see the `Sprite` being disposed anywhere. How should the `Sprite` be being disposed of?

Comment: You don't dispose of the sprite.  You dispose of the texture assigned to the sprite.  Which you can only do if you make a variable for it before giving it to the sprite.